# Fail to build in Jenkins with perforce guest account

Tags: jenkins, perforce, ranorex

For specific reason, we want to change the perforce login account with a perforce guest account.

However, after we just changed the credentials, Jenkins report error message when try to build with parameters:
P4: Unable to setup workspace: com.perforce.p4java.exception.RequestException: Error in client specification.
Mapping '//**/test/Ranorex/RxProject/...' is not under '//**/...'.[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1k6Z.png)
The weird thing is that after we change the credentials with a specific account, Jenkins can be build successfully. (On the slave machine, we can log in with perforce guest account successfully)You can refer to below with the configuration info in the source code management tab.
[Perforce configuration in Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4h0r.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's not a permissions error, it's a client spec error. When you changed login credentials, my guess would be that you have a problem with your build client working properly with the new user.

Try logging into the build machine with the new user, and running:

`p4 -u<new user> -c<build client> sync -m1 -n //...`

See what happens. I suspect you'll get the same error message. Or perhaps one that's slightly more useful.